# How to make textarea scrollbar cursor as pointer (hand icon)?

Tags: html, css, cursor, textarea, scrollbar

How to make textarea scrollbar cursor as pointer, keeping the textarea cursor as text. Now it shows default cursor(text cursor and arrow cursor).

```css
textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  cursor: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<textarea> asdasd <br> asdasd <br> asdasd <br> asdasd <br> asdasd <br> </textarea>
```

Comment: set the cursor to the textarea itself instead of the scrollbar

Comment: @tacoshy But it will make whole text area as pointer cursor

Answer (score 1):

Why did you set the cursor as auto if it's the pointer you need, just change that in `textarea`

after the change :

```
textarea {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

textarea might look like this.

Comment: i'm looking for text icon on text area and hand icon on scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

I know the post is a little old, but maybe it will help somebody.

You had it almost correct! Just remove the second CSS selector, "textarea::-webkit-scrollbar". Setting `cursor: auto;` on the textarea will give it a text cursor while hovering over the text, and a pointer while hovering over the scrollbar. here's a working sample you can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    textarea {
      width: 350px;
      cursor: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Scrollbar cursor demo</h1>
  <textarea rows="5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Set `cursor: pointer` and then on focus return the cursor to auto to give it the experience of clicking on the text box to activate it

```css
textarea { cursor: pointer }
textarea:focus { cursor: auto }
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="60">Adipiscing habitasse lacinia vestibulum a habitant ante ut a inceptos scelerisque elit himenaeos varius tincidunt. Fusce fringilla eros arcu pharetra scelerisque etiam magnis adipiscing adipiscing nunc scelerisque vestibulum fames nisi mauris. Vestibulum nibh egestas per vel ultrices platea placerat mi in a mi at quam ultrices a magna vel auctor mus. Cubilia parturient scelerisque ultrices at et est condimentum eu nibh sapien quam elementum ligula vestibulum ultrices lectus metus suspendisse. Taciti mus nulla habitasse habitasse bibendum augue condimentum vulputate eget libero sed venenatis malesuada netus consectetur ut. Sit porttitor iaculis a sem urna vestibulum a parturient a per ultricies faucibus hac cursus vestibulum interdum per nisl a faucibus.</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. But I want hand icon on the scrollbar and text icon on textarea.